# How to resolve the promise object

Tags: angular, ngrx

I want to get data from service used ngrx/store, and than I get a promise object from reducer, how to resolve the promise object to display on web page.

service

```js
get(request){
  return this.httpClient.get<any>(uri).toPromise().then(res => <Node[]>res);
}
```

action

```js
getNodeData(name){
    return this.service.get(name);
}
```

reducer

```js
export function nodeReducre(
  state = initNode,
  action: Action
) {
  switch (action.type):
    case 'GetNode':
      state = action.getNodeData(name);
      return state;
    default:
      return initNode;
}
```

component.ts

```js
node$: Observalbe<Node[]> = this.store.pipe(select('node'));
```

component.html

```html
{{node$|async}}
```

Display '[object Promise]' at webpage.

stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yebobf

Comment: What is the need to convert `Observable` to `Promise` in your service?. If that is not required then use directly `Observable`. `async` pipe only works for `Observables` not for `promises` and `this.store.pipe(select('node'))` is returning `promise` instead of `observable`. If you want to use `async` pipe then use `observable` or you need to resolve `promise` into your component `.ts` file.

Comment: @ArunRedhu I remove toPromise at service, still cannot resolve on webpage. did I need to subscribe at reducer?

Comment: Can you share a working fiddle or stackblitz around this ??

Comment: @ArunRedhu I update my question and append demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to working with `async` actions in `ngrx`. `Async` actions are handled using the `effects`. I have updated forked your working demo and did some changes using effects. I created an effect as `app-effect.ts` in your sample. Observe some changes done by me in `app.component.ts`, `app.module.ts`, `app-reducer.ts`, `app-action.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class AppEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    public nodeSvc: DemoService
  ) {}

  @Effect()
  viewNodes$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType(DemoActions.requestNodeAction),
      mergeMap((data) => {
        return this.nodeSvc.getObjectCallChain(data.payload)
        .pipe(
          map(data => ({ type: DemoActions.receivedNodeAction, payload: data })),
          catchError(() => EMPTY)
        )
      })
      )
}
```

You can find the updated example here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gni7vu

Also, you can study in details about `ngrx effects` here

https://ngrx.io/guide/effects

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use asynchronous code in reducer.
Use effects for that.

Short example:

```
@Effect()
loadData$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('GetData'),
    map((action) => action.payload),
    switchMap((payload: any) =>
        this.service.get(payload)
            .pipe(
                map((data: any) => new SuccessAction(data)),
                catchError((error: any) => of(new FailureAction(error)))
            )
    )
);
```

Look at the [docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects) for more detail.

Action File:

```
export class GetData implements Action {
     readonly type = 'GetData';

     constructor(public payload: any) {}
}
```

Comment: the get method of service must have 1 args. how to pass args to effects?